# What is the explanation for this syntax of a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

The book offers no explanation on this style, but chances are that I just couldn't find it.

The question is: Let *V*, vector space, be the first quadrant in the xy-plane; that is,

let *V* = {[x y](<- Shown vertically) : x >= 0, y >= 0}.

The question isn't fully posted, but I would like some clarification on what the book means when it writes this notation down. What are the statements after the colon? Is the statement before the colon a vector in R2?

Comment: It is saying $V$ is the set of all vectors $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ such that $x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$.

Comment: @Rahul This clears everything up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard notation for vectors $\vec v=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb {R^2}$ as a column vector.

In that context the row vector $[x\: y]$ is indicated by $\vec v^T$.